# Terraform AWS provider not finding route table from subnet_id

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get the route table associated with a subnet. It seems like the AWS provider is not correctly finding the subnet? I attempted to follow the documentation, but I get this error:

```
│ Error: query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again
│
│   with data.aws_route_table.selected,
│   on main.tf line 1, in data "aws_route_table" "selected":
│  1: data "aws_route_table" "selected" {
│
```

Here is the relevant documentation I'm following:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route_table

Here is the example I used as a reference:

```
data "aws_route_table" "selected" {
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
}
```

Here's what I wrote:

```
data "aws_route_table" "selected" {
  subnet_id = "subnet-1234567890abcdefg"
}
```

If I use the route table ID, then it works:

```
data "aws_route_table" "selected" {
  route_table_id = "rtb-1234567890abcdefg"
}
```

I noticed that if I do a `terraform state show data.aws_route_table.selected` on the working example, there is no `subnet_id` listed as an attribute.

Comment: Does your subnet actually have a RT associated with it?

Comment: @Marcin It did not have an explicit subnet association, but I assumed that it would still return the main route table. It appears that is not the case, however.

Comment: Yes, it must be associated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `aws_route_table` and `aws_route_tables` resources will only return route tables explicitly associated with the subnet. If the subnet uses the main route table, then terraform won't return that.

In my example, there was no explicit subnet association - the subnet was using the main route table. As soon as I added an explicit subnet association, the data block started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`aws_route_table` can only fetch the details in which the subnets are explicitly associated. default route table will not have explicitly associated subnets.

[Screenshot of default route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3JMF.png)

Assuming you intend to retrieve the default route table created during VPC creation, you can obtain the route table by using the VPC ID

```
data "aws_route_table" "default_routetable" {
  vpc_id = vpc-05f7cb5d09ec15853
}
```